# SwiftUI: Get view's frame on tap?

Tags: swiftui

Is there a way to get the view's frame when its `onTapGesture` executes?

```
.onTapGesture {

   ... get the view's frame.... 

}
```

I would like to tap on viewA, get its frame, and use that for custom internal logic.

Comment: Hard to do in SwiftUI... GeometryReader might be useful, but it tends to mess up your layouts. Maybe you're looking for [`matchedGeometryEffect`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-synchronize-animations-from-one-view-to-another-with-matchedgeometryeffect)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it inside a `GeometryReader` and use the proxy:

```
GeometryReader { proxy in
    ,,,

    .onTapGesture {
        print(proxy.frame(in: .global))
    }
}
```